Mysql LIKE or REGEXP
I am trying to select all the strings has word ABC1 in it. But getting wrong answer with LIKE query. Not sure how to get exact answer.
Below is the string format in a column:
"SomeString ABC1000 Other";
And I don't want to select any String which is in the format like 
"itisABC1000 other other"

All strings from a single column, all strings from all the columns, or search every single table and every single column?

'%ABC1%'. Post query, please

So you require ABC1 to be at the beginning of a word? Use a regexp, with the [:<:] word beginning pattern.

LIKE can't do this.

with reular expression you can use REGEXP\_LIKE
this oirks for MYsql 8.x
select REGEXP_LIKE("SomeString ABC1000 Other",'ABC1')




REGEXP_LIKE("SomeString ABC1000 Other",'ABC1')




1



fiddle
Your query would wlook like
SELECT yourcolmuns FROM your_table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(yourlike_column,'ABC1')

for older Versions like 5.7
select "SomeString ABC1000 Other" REGEXP 'ABC1'




"SomeString ABC1000 Other" REGEXP 'ABC1'




1



fiddle
so the query would look like
SELECT yourcolmuns FROM your_table WHERE yourlike_column REGEXP 'ABC1'


I think your answer is right. But regexp_like is an Oracle function. And I am using Mysql. It gave error as FUNCTION mysql.regexp_like does not exist

this was introduced in MySQL 8.x but i added for 5.7, if you are older you should think about updating the version

Found answer with LIKE
select column 
from table
where conditions like "% ABC1%" or conditions like "ABC1%";
Thank you!

Often people do something like concat(' ',conditions) like '% ABC1%'
